# Python module inside a package

Tags: python, package

I have a folder called `myPackage` which contains

- a file called `__init__.py`
- a file called `myModule.py`

The file `__init__.py` is as follows:

```
from .myModule import *
```

The file `myModule.py` is as follows:

```
def foo():
    print("Hello!")
```

The following script runs as I would expect:

```
import myPackage
myPackage.foo()
```

What I really don't understand is why the following script *also* works:

```
import myPackage 
myPackage.myModule.foo()
```

I would have expected the second script not to work: after all, myPackage "does not have a myModule defined in it".

EDIT: The reason I am surprised is because the second script below, in the following modified example, fails...

I have two files `myModule.py` and `myModule2.py`

The file `myModule.py` is as follows:

```
from myModule2 import *
```

The file `myModule2.py` is as follows:

```
def foo():
    print("Hello!")
```

The "equivalent" of the first script above runs as I would expect:

```
import myModule
myModule.foo()
```

But now the "equivalent" of the second script does *not* work..

```
import myModule
myModule.myModule2.foo()
```

Comment: `myPackage "does not have a myModule defined in it".` Sure it does. It's a *package*, after all. There's a `myModule.py` in the `myPackage` folder. You can easily confirm this by doing `dir(myPackage)`, or `myPackage.myModule`. If you want to understand overall what the import system does, you should **read the documentation**; and then, if and when you are confused, you can ask a specific question with a citation in that documentation - **after** searching for answers elsewhere (and demonstrating exactly how you searched).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am reading a book to try and learn. I am sorry if I am not as smart as you. I will edit the question to make it even clearer why I am surprised by this behavior. If you think that there s already an answer to my question (my apologies in this case), you re welcome to point that to me..